# Correct way of using invoke_result?

Tags: c++, c++17, forwarding-reference, result-of

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), it is written that the correct way of using `std::result_of` is:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
std::result_of_t<F&&(Args&&...)> 
// instead of std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>, which is wrong
  my_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) { 
    /* implementation */
}
```

I was wondering how `std::invoke_result_t` should be used:
`invoke_result_t`:

```
template<class F, class... Args> 
std::invoke_result_t<F&&, Args&&...> my_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

Or:

```
template<class F, class... Args> 
std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> my_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`invoke_result`](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.other) is defined in terms of `declval`:

> If the expression `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand, the member typedef `type` names the type `decltype(INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...));` otherwise, there shall be no member `type`.

and [`declval`](http://eel.is/c++draft/declval#lib:declval) is specified as:

> ```
> template<class T> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;
> ```

So there's no difference between `std::invoke_result_t<F&&, Args&&...>` and `std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>`. Well, the latter is 4 characters shorter, but they mean exactly the same thing (since neither `F` nor `Args...` could be `void`).

Comment: There might be oddball cases where you get the template arguments from somewhere else and one isn't referenceable, in which case the `&&` version may cause an error while the plain version doesn't. But it's pretty far-fetched.

Comment: Caveat is, if your return type is void, the invoke_result_t is void and ::type doesn't exist...

Comment: @cerkiewny Which `::type` doesn't exist? `invoke_result_t` works fine for `void` return types.

Comment: well I have the problem in which apparently the ::type doesn't exsit for invoke_result<function_returning_void> ::type, I need to investigate further though as behaviour clearly varies between gcc and clang, it might be a problem somewhere else in my system, trying to create minimal example with the difference